# What does this code mean in the finale of Better Call Saul?

Tags: plot-explanation, better-call-saul

In the finale of *Better Call Saul*, Saul/Gene/McGill is hiding in a dumpster; he finds a piece of paper from a bandage and it reads:

> Hoover Max Extract Pressure-Pro, model sixty

As soon as he finishes reading it, he attempts to use an unwrapped burner phone, I can guess that this code has something to do with the vacuum man who specialises in helping criminals to escape, but how does it translate into a phone number?

Comment: You didn't watch Breaking Bad / El Camino. What a miss :)

Comment: @Déjàvu: You don't have had to watch those to know what it means. See answer below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The piece of paper is the business card of the vacuum repairman. "Hoover Max Extract Pressure-Pro, model sixty" is not a phone number, it's the passphrase to let the vacuum repairman know that you're looking to "disappear" — be extracted and have your identity changed.

Saul mentioned the passphrase the first time he called the vacuum repairman in  [S04E05 "Quite A Ride"](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Quite_a_Ride) (relevant part starts at 03:42):

> **Saul Goodman:** I need a new dust filter for my Hoover Max Extract Pressure-Pro Model Sixty. Can you help me with that?
> A pickup.
> How hot? Red hot.

In *El Camino*, Jesse Pinkman tried to tell the passphrase to the vacuum repairman but does not have the exact passphrase memorized:

> **Jesse:** Umm, I'm looking for a Hoover Max… Pressure Max. Max Pressure. Hoover, maybe it's a Pro Max. Hell, like a — like a filter?
> **Vacuum repairman:** Hoover products are right over there at the wall behind you.
> **Jesse:** Look, I don't remember the exact like password, alright but it's a vacuum thing.

Comment: I bet if an ordinary customer had a malfunctioning "Hoover Max Extract Pressure-Pro, model sixty" and called up for a repair, they were going to be in for some serious sticker shock when they got the estimate. LOL (such a model DOES exist: https://www.amazon.com/Hoover-Extract-Pressure-Cleaner-FH50220/dp/B0043VSR8E?th=1 )

Comment: @BrandonXavier Maybe the phone number they call goes to a very specific cell phone, only used by people who want to "disappear"? Ed was a cautious man.